# Sensitivity analysis of computationally expensive model

Tags: sensitivity-analysis

I have a finite element model of a geometric structure which is computationally expensive to solve. The model is parameterized with 3 parameters.
Each configuration is solved for an increasing load between `0` and `load_max` at `n` discrete loads.
So the output (a specific property of the geometric structure) per configuration is a series of `n` values.
I evaluated `3^3=27` combinations of these parameters.

Given the input combinations and the 27 output value series, how can I perform a sensitivity analysis to quantify the influence of each parameter on the output value and to determine which parameter combination can minimize the output value?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is properly described as "sensitivity-analysis". It seems more like standard experimental design issues in engineering. Are you assuming / worried about the possibility of interactions? If not, [tag:fractional-factorial] designs are worth exploring.

Comment: Yes,  I assume  that there are interactions between the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

With only 27 data points (and you haven't said how precise these values are), you should be concerned about overfitting the data.  I'd start by fitting a simple quadratic response surface model and see whether the predictions look reasonable.